# NSDictionary having null value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a problem when Extracting data from a Dictionary object. Count of the Dictionary is displaying as 1, but the one value it is displaying is null. I want to display a AlertView when there is no data in the Dictionary object. I thought of displaying the AlertView when the count is '0', but it returning '1'.

I am extracting this dictionary object from a WebService using JSON.

```
{
     "My Data" = null;
}
```

Used this code for getting the "My Data" value into the Dictionary variable Datas.

```
Datas = (NSDictionary *) [details objectForKey:@"My Data"];

if ([Datas count] == 0) {

//code for showing AlertView....

}
```

Please help me to display a UIAlertView when the Dictionary value having null....

Comment: put the `NSLog` for details and Dates... check what it returns....

Comment: Hi Kalyan, could you give a little bit more code. I don't understand what you try to achieve...

Comment: +1 for trying at least something... Why are honest questions always being down voted

Answer (score 43):

`NSDictionary` and other collections cannot contain `nil` values. When `NSDictionary` must store a `null`, a special value [`[NSNull null]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is stored.

Compare the value at `@"My Data"` to `[NSNull null]` to determine if the corresponding value is `null` or not.

```
// Since [NSNull null] is a singleton, you can use == instead of isEqual
if ([details objectForKey:@"My Data"] == [NSNull null]) {
    // Display the alert
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Usually null values in JSON get parsed to `NSNull`. So this condition should check for that as well as nil: `if((details[@"My Data"] == nil) || (details[@"My Data"] == [NSNull null]))`

Answer (score 5):

```
if ([[details objectForKey:@"My Data"] isEqual:[NSNull null]] || [[details objectForKey:@"My Data"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
     UIAlertView *altTemp = [UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Value Null" message:@"Your Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
     [altTemp show];
     [altTemp release];
}
```

Comment: now , its right?? @PratyushaTerli i just write the answer which give some idea so just skip that point so, but thanx :)

Comment: Why test isEqUal:NULL? If that is true it will evaluate to false and won't work for nsnull

Comment: @CarlVeazey now its right?? and no some time from server we get value null in string also, so just convert it to string and it will work so i just define above code, and now its right... what you say??

Comment: @CarlVeazey now its true and right and first i write NULL bcoz some time from api , and server may be return direct that type of values so.. if now right then upvote me..